# Passing in a text to a javascript function that may have a single quote

Tags: javascript

I have a link that I dynamically create which looks something like the following:

```
<a onclick="Edit('value from a text column here')" href="javascript:void(null);">Edit</a>
```

with the Edit function then taking the passed in value and putting it into a Yahoo Rich Text Editor. This works well except for when there is a single quote in the text being passed. The obvious problem being that the link then looks something like:

```
<a onclick="Edit('I'm a jelly donut')" href="javascript:void(null);">Edit</a>
```

Any suggestions on what I can do? I'd rather not stray too far from the structure I am currently using because it is something of a standard (and maybe the standard sucks, but that's another question altogether).

Note: I am using ASP as my server side language.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Convert quote charaters to their HTML equivalents, `&quot;` etc. before you insert them into the HTML. There's a [long list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references) of HTML/XML character codes on wikipedia.

There may well be a function to do this for you, depending on how you're dynamically generating the code: PHP has [htmlspecialchars](http://uk.php.net/htmlspecialchars), and though I'm not familiar with ASP etc, I'm sure there are similar routines.

Comment: "&apos;" worked for me, whereas \' and \u0027 didn't, probably because I was constructing the html within javascript, e.g.:    1:  var html = "<a href='javascript:void(0);' onclick='ShowName(\"{0}\");'>Click Me</a>       2:  html = html.replace("{0}", item.Name.replace("'","&apos;"));

Answer (score 3):

You could just replace the ' with \'

Answer (score 1):

Run the text through an escape function to put a \ before the '. If you're generating the link on the server, we would need to know what server-side language you're using to give more specific advice.

If you're generating the tag client-side as a string in javascript (don't do that, use document.createElement), use the [String.replace](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp) method on the argument string to pick out characters that will break the syntax you're generating and replace them with escaped versions.

Answer (score 1):

I see at least three additional possibilities:

#### JavaScript Unicode escape

```
<a onclick="Edit('I\u0027m a jelly donut')" href="javascript:void(null);">Edit</a>
```

as \u0027 is the javascript espace character for the quote. The others being less practical:

#### JavaScript function

```
<script>function getQuote() { return "'" }</script>
<a onclick="Edit('I' + getQuote() + 'm a jelly donut')" href="javascript:void(null);">Edit</a>
```

and:

#### JavaScript global variable

```
<script>var g_strJellyText = "I\u0027m a jelly donut"</script>
<a onclick="Edit(g_strJellyText)" href="javascript:void(null);">Edit</a>
```

But I believe you already considered theses solution (or their variants, or the HTML entity escape mentionned by Chris Johnson).

Still, it's worth mentioning.

Answer (score 0):

So it seems there was more going on, most of these would probably work under most circumstances, but in the interest of posterity here's what I had to do.

The information being pulled into the Rich Text Editor was in a YUI datatable and I am creating a link using the custom formatter prototype for said control.

The problem with using the "Replace ' with \' " method was that I need to still view the text being displayed in the datatable the same way.

The problem with using the ASP equivalent of htmlspecialchars (Server.HTMLEncode) was that it still had a problem in the javascript that was being generated from the custom formatter function. I don't know why exactly, but I did try it and it didn't work. That answer was closest to the answer that I came up with (and pushed me in the right direction) so I accepted that answer.

What I did instead was used the javascript function 'escape' to pass into my edit function, and then unescape to set the inner HTML for the Rich Text Editor.