# ASP.NET Error when binding a GridView to a List of Objects?

Tags: asp.net, gridview, data-binding

### Error Message:

> The data source for GridView with id 'FormProprietari' did not have
>   any properties or attributes from which to generate columns.  Ensure
>   that your data source has content.

I have a ASP.NEt application in which I try to bind a `GridView` to a `List<T>` objects which from what I can tell on the net it should be possible.

This is my `GridView`:

```
<asp:GridView ID="FormProprietari" runat="server">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField >
                 <ItemTemplate> 
                    <%#((Lab_TAP_web.Proprietar)Container.DataItem).NumeProprietar%> 
                 </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

            <asp:TemplateField >
                 <ItemTemplate> 
                    <%#((Lab_TAP_web.Proprietar)Container.DataItem).PrenumeProprietar%> 
                 </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

            <asp:TemplateField >
                 <ItemTemplate> 
                    <%#((Lab_TAP_web.Proprietar)Container.DataItem).ProprietarID%> 
                 </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>

    </asp:GridView>
```

And this is the function in which I add a new object of the `Proprietar` class I defined to the database then rebind the gridview to show it, I should mention that intially the database is empty and so is the gridview i,e it doesn't show up.

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var Nume = TBNumeProprietar.Text;
            var Prenume = TBPreNumeProprietar.Text;

            MyCars db = DBSilo.db;

            Proprietar newOwner = new Proprietar();
            newOwner.NumeProprietar = Nume;
            newOwner.PrenumeProprietar = Prenume;
            newOwner.ProprietarID = (db.Proprietari.Count() + 1);
            //newOwner.ProprietarID = 1;



            db.Proprietari.InsertOnSubmit(newOwner);
            db.SubmitChanges();

            try
            {
                FormProprietari.DataSource = db.Proprietari.ToList();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                throw;
            }
            FormProprietari.DataBind();           
        }
```

The problem being that I checked the `List<Proprietar>` which is the data source with breakpoints and the list always contains a `Proprietar` object.

Does anyone have a idea what I did wrong?

Comment: if you try Reponse.Write(db.Proprietari.Count().ToString()) does it give you a 1?

Comment: Yes it returns a 1, which is corect as there should be only 1 row.

Comment: You want to develop step-by-step. 1) Insert test records to database, and see those records display in `GridView`. 2) Then develop insert/update/delete.

Comment: @Win I'm sorry I'm not getting you, I've inserted test records in the db they exist I'm sure of it, what I'm trying to do is get them to show up which causes the error I posted, I don't need anything more from the gridview but to see the rows I inserted.

Comment: Please make sure you have getter and setter for each property of `Proprietar` class. If still not working, create a collection like this (without database) and debug/test GridView - http://stackoverflow.com/a/16407618/296861

Comment: @Win That was it I didn't knew I needed getters and setter (I left them public and thought it was enough) could you please convert your comment into a answer so we can mark it properly as the right answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Moved from comment to Answer.**

Please make sure you have getter and setter for each property of `Proprietar` class like this -

```
public class Proprietar
{
    public string NumeProprietar { get; set; }
    public string PrenumeProprietar { get; set; }
    public int ProprietarID { get; set; }
}
```